# Dotnet Core: Display Multiple image files filtered by name

Tags: c#, image, file, asp.net-core, .net-core

Let's say I want to display a couple of images in my Razor view. The number of the images I want to display depends on how many of them meet a certain conditions, like how many files' names in that folder begin with `{id}`, e.g. `~/img/solutions/{year}/{variant}/{id}.png` and `~/img/solutions/{year}/{variant}/{id}-1.png`

The algorithm would be look at that folder, check the files, pick the ones which meet certain naming condition, select the relative path, put it in a collection which I can simply foreach in the view. How can I achieve that?

EDIT: As suggested by [Rajesh G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828907/rajesh-g) I'm just going to add what I have so far

```
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Variables for a simple example
        var year = 17;
        var variant = 1;
        var id = 1;

        var webRoot = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var appData = Path.Combine(webRoot, $"img/solutions/{year}/{variant}/{id}.png");

        var model = Directory.EnumerateFiles(appData).Select(x => Url.Content(x));

        return View(model);
    }
```

This code works, though the string passed to the view is not yet trimmed to the relative path. It picks up only the file with the exact name. I want to change that code so it picks up not just `{id}.png` but `{id}-1.png` and `{id}-2.png` if they're available in that directory.

Using `{id}*.png` or `{id}*` in the following line made the app throw exceptions.

```
var appData = Path.Combine(webRoot, $"img/solutions/{year}/{variant}/{id}*.png");
```

Comment: share the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came up with a way that works for me.

For better or worse I changed the logic – instead of picking `{id}*.*` from `~/img/solutions/{year}/{variant}/` I make a new folder for these and pick everything that's inside `~/img/solutions/{year}/{variant}/{id}/` because that's the only way I can make it work.

```
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var year = 17;
            var variant = 1;
            var id = 1;

            var webRoot = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var relativePath = $"/img/solutions/{year}/{variant}/{id}/";
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(webRoot, $"img/solutions/{year}/{variant}/{id}");

            var model = Directory.EnumerateFiles(fullPath)
                             .Select(file => relativePath + Path.GetFileName(file));

            return View(model);
        }
```